# using Shmget() in c with structure

Tags: c, shared-memory

am using C on OSx and using shmget() to get memory to be used between two different programs i
have a structure of 2 int values 
does this mean if i want a size of 27 instead it will have to be 54 and how would this work with the pointers used for the structure or any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: A structure of two `int` values would normally be 8 or 16 bytes big (depending on if you're on a 32 or 64 bit platform). Where does the numbers 27 and 54 come from?

Comment: my 27/54 where the amount of ints i forgot about  the size of the int as i have only see shmget used with char

Answer (score 1):

No, you need to use sizeof on the struct.  You can't guarantee how the implementation will pad the values inside the struct, so you don't assume the size of them.  Also, if the size changes later due to adding member(s) to the struct, the memory allocation will still work correctly.

Then use that value from sizeof to multiply by the number of instances of the struct you intend to use in the shared memory area.

Comment: will this mean that the size of functions then will allow the program to increment by the size of the structure and if so how would that be done

Comment: @Milmar I am not sure I understand the additional question above correctly.  Perhaps it would be helpful to provide an example of what you are trying to do currently.

Comment: so for the first struct location i add the following values (1,2) how do i then get to the next memory location i know for a char value i can increment my pointer by 1 to get the next location

Comment: Since you don't seem to have any code yet, you might want to look at this older question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671336/how-does-one-keep-an-int-and-an-array-in-shared-memory-in-c?rq=1 which has some helpful links and code examples.  In fact, there are a fairly large number of existing shared memory questions already.  It would probably very helpful if you read through them.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have a struct like this:

```
typedef struct {
    int aCount;
    int bCount;
    int cCount;
} data_t;
```

This below function will create shared memory for the specified size.

```
int shared_memory_create(size_t memory_size)
{
    int shm_key = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, memory_size, IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | 0666);
    if(shm_key < 0) {
        perror("Failed to Create Shared Memory Key");
        exit(0);
    }

    return shm_key;
}
```

If you want to create shared memory to accommodate 27 elements, call the function ***shared_memory_create*** as shown below:

```
shm_key = shared_memory_create(27*sizeof(data_t));
```